# display text value on EditText on run time

Tags: java, android

I'm a novice in java and android development. I'm developing this very basic 4x4 sudoku app wherein m trying to display some text values based on the game number. However, at run time the text in the EditText field displays blank.

**Below is the code in onCreate()**

```
    a=gamenumber(); //returns a random game number
    displayrandommatrix(a); 
    findviewbyidfunc();
```

**Below is the sample code for displaying values in EditText**

```
           public void displayrandommatrix(int n)
            {
            switch(n)
            {
            case 1:
        r11.setText("2");
        r12.setText("3");
        r23.setText("3");
        r24.setText("2");
        r32.setText("4");
        r33.setText("2");
        r41.setText("1");
        r44.setText("3");
        break;
            case 2:
        r12.setText("2");
        r13.setText("4");
        r21.setText("1");
        r24.setText("3");
        r31.setText("4");
        r34.setText("2");
        r42.setText("1");
        r43.setText("3");
        break;
               }
```

**This is the code I'm using for random game number.**

```
              public int gamenumber()
            {
        int b=randint.charAt(r.nextInt(randint.length()));
        return b;       
            }

         public void findviewbyidfunc()
       {
    checksol=(Button)findViewById(R.id.checksol1);
    r11=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.row1col1);
    r21=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.row2col1);
    r31=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.row3col1);
    r41=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.row4col1);
      }
```

**List of Logcat errors:**
10-21 06:15:12.564: E/AndroidRuntime(1467): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-21 06:15:12.564: E/AndroidRuntime(1467): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sudokunew/com.example.sudokunew.Level2_play}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-21 06:15:12.564: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
10-21 06:15:12.564: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
10-21 06:15:12.564: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-21 06:15:12.564: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
10-21 06:15:12.564: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-21 06:15:12.564: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-21 06:15:12.564: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-21 06:15:12.564: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-21 06:15:12.564: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-21 06:15:12.564: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-21 06:15:12.564: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-21 06:15:12.564: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-21 06:15:12.564: E/AndroidRuntime(1467): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-21 06:15:12.564: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     at com.example.sudokunew.Level2_play.displayrandommatrix(Level2_play.java:177)
10-21 06:15:12.564: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     at com.example.sudokunew.Level2_play.onCreate(Level2_play.java:26)
10-21 06:15:12.564: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
10-21 06:15:12.564: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
10-21 06:15:12.564: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
10-21 06:15:12.564: E/AndroidRuntime(1467):     ... 11 more

Comment: What's in findviewbyidfunc?

Comment: see my answer, that is your error..according to the logs..

Answer (score 0):

EditTexts have a Hint element which can be set. This is the text that shows if the users hasn't put in any text of his own.

Answer (score 0):

your question is not well posed, it's not clear what you need, and it's not clear where should be the problem: the random generator funcion? or the findViewById function?
for the random generator I recommend to use built-in Java code:

```
Random rand = new Random(); //initialize this only one time, at the beginning, in the onCreate() method of your activity.    
int a = rand.nextInt(MAX_VALUE);
```

for the findViewById function, have you done all of the calls, like this?

```
r11 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.R11_ID);
r12 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.R12_ID);
r13 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.R13_ID);
... and so on
```

Comment: ok, but where's your problem? the EditText does not display anything? but if you log something in every switch case, it prints in the logcat? or doesn't even enter the switch? Print in the logcat the string that you would like to display in the EditText, it that is correct there must be a problem elsewhere. You have no exception in the logcat?

Comment: EditText doesn't display anything.Possibly the random number is not entering the switch case. I started getting exceptions after adding the default case. I've posted them above.

Answer (score 0):

switch case may be the issue,
It may hit default case, if appropriate case is not handled.
put default case in switch with appropriate code.

like

```
default:
    r11.setText("2");

    r12.setText("3");
    r23.setText("3");
    r24.setText("2");
    r32.setText("4");
    r33.setText("2");
    r41.setText("1");
    r44.setText("3");
```

Comment: added the default section but there seems to be lot of exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

To generate random number use the following lines of code

```
static Random ran1=new Random();
static int ranInt1;
ranInt1= ran1.nextInt(9)+1;
```

Comment: If my answer helps you you can except this as an answer

Answer (score 0):

First of All the findviewbyidfunc() should be above the displayrandommatrix(a) function. Only then will it get the resource id of the EditText.

I think then it may display the values. Also it will give an exception according to your code if displayrandommatrix(a) is above findviewbyidfunc(), because the displayrandommatrix(a) method does not have the id's of the edittext's

Secondly, after moving findviewbyidfunc() above, check by debugging whether the random number is the number among the switch case numbers, else it will not go in the cases of switch then nothing will be displayed.

Comment: moved the function findviewbyidfunc() above the other functions and it worked.. Thanks a lot for pointing this out.

Comment: ur welcome my friend, you can tick this as answer if it solved your issue.